# Get all items from the loop and show json

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel` and `PHP` and am double looping though a list of id's to get a list of products by id's have have been mapped in the first loop.

Because i'm returning the response, it's only returning the first results the list.

How can I return all the items in the list as json so I can output this from my api?

```
            //Loop through and make additional calls to get all storage
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                // Make additional API calls based on the $id
                $data = Http::get($url.'/'.$id);
                if($data->successful()) {
                   return response()->json(json_decode($data)); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Push them into an array _inside_ the loop, and return that array encoded as JSON _after_ the loop ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
//Loop through and make additional calls to get all storage
$results = [];

foreach ($ids as $id) {
   // Make additional API calls based on the $id
   $data = Http::get($url.'/'.$id);
   if($data->successful()) {
        $results[] = json_decode($data); 
   }
}

return response()->json($results);
```

Comment: Thanks...I did this before, must have left something off...